# Como passar um parâmetro para DataPrpetyName (no DataGrid) C#

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso passar um parâmetro ali? Por exemplo mudar o id_inss para id_exemplo?

Não achei nenhuma forma de fazer.

Comment: passar parâmetro ou mudar o nome da propriedade ? nessa tela, basta mudar... vc quer via código ?  se sim, você tem que alterar a propriedade da DataGridViewColumn, já que está mexendo em uma...

Comment: Então quero "colocar" o valor de uma variável para alterar a propriedade, e dependendo desse "valor" mudar a propriedade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você adiciona uma coluna ao `DataGridView`, você cria um objeto `DataGridViewColumn`, que no seu código é chamado de `codigo` (ali na propriedade `Name`). Então, você pode alterar qualquer valor do objeto.

Exemplo:

```
string p = "id_exemplo";
codigo.DataPropertyName = p;
```

também é equivalente à:

```
string p = "id_exemplo";
dataGridView1.Columns[codigo.Name].DataPropertyName = p;
```

> Recomendo rever os nomes das variáveis e propriedades.

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado!!!

Comment: Obrigado !!!!!!!!